# Is there any significant difference between `->` and `.` for accessing struct members?

Tags: c, struct, coding-style

While it may be *very* obvious to those familiar with C and its nuances, I'm not as familiar with either and can't tell if there is any *significant* difference between accessing a struct's member using `->` or `.`.

Like if I have `struct my_struct`:

```c
struct my_struct {
  int x;
  int y;
};

struct my_struct grid;
```

Does it make a difference, beyond differing syntax, whether I access `struct my_struct grid`'s `x` member via `grid.x` or `grid->x`?  And if there is a difference, which one should I prefer?

Tried searching google/SO, but I didn't find anything that mentioned which one was the preferred, if any, method.  Both seem correct, but I can't help but feel that one of them (`->`) has a more specialized use-case.

Comment: Try compile the code with `grid.x` and `grid->x`, you'll see the error.

Comment: @YuHao I see what you mean, so `->` is only for pointers to structures?

Comment: The difference between `.` and `->` is hardly a nuance. They are completely different operators. I know you said you googled but this is such an elementary subject it shouldn't have been hard to find. I googled `c accessing struct members` and the [4th link down](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080204004626AAmQ9cP) answers your question as well. Just try to put a little more effort in next time.

Comment: @Yu Hao, the MS compiler has an extension that you can go `p_grid.x` and `p_grid->x` for pointers ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how the struct is declared. If we have an actual struct variable, use `.`. If we have a pointer to a struct, use `->`:

```
struct my_struct *s = ...;
s->x = 5;
printf("%d\n", s->x);

struct my_struct s2 = ...;
s2.x = 4;
printf("%d\n", s2.x);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
x->foo
```

is shorthand for:

```
(*x).foo
```

which, as others have observed, only makes sense if x is a pointer to a struct.

Answer (score 0):

A simple rule to remember when to use '.' and when to use '->'  (generally)...

```
abc->def   or   abc.def
```

When 'abc' is defined as a pointer, use '->':

```
struct XYZ
   {
   int def;
   } *abc;

abc->def = 1;
```

When 'abc' is not defined as a pointer, use '.':

```
struct XYZ
   {
   int def;
   } abc;

abc.def = 1
```